# Is there a way to copy an HTML tokenizer in Go?

Tags: html, go, tokenize, meta-tags

I am trying to tokenize HTML meta data, including some opg. I have tokenizer `tokenizer := html.NewTokenizer(htmlStream)` to iterate through the tags.

But for the opg `og:img` tag, there may be multiple images and the properties that are immediately following the previous `og:img` tag are the properties on that one. So for example, from opg

```
<meta property="og:image:width" content="300" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/rock2.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/rock3.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="1000" />
```

I need to know the next property first to decide whether to start a new or add to existing image object. It seems like there is a no function similar to `peek`, it came up to me things like the two iterators in an array, but Go is reporting errors and empty tags when I started and used a new tokenizer `imageTokenizer := html.NewTokenizer(htmlStream)`, is there a way that I can do that. TBH I have gone too far in this approach without first testing the tokenizer. But I am also willing to listen to other approaches on this.

Comment: No, you will have to remember all properties while scanning them and attach them to the og:img once your read that tag. (You can neither peek in the stream nor "reconsume" the stream: It is a _stream_.)

Comment: Aside from that, it seems like a bad idea to me to rely on the order of header tags. In general, this sounds like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me. Why would you want  to have meta properties containing an image when you have and `img`tag? And if you have a custom parser, why not encode it as `<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/rock2.jpg?og.w=300&og.h=300">`